# Using ffmpeg option -video_track_timescale 25 produces a video with 1k tbn. Why is this?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am recording a live audio stream with an image using this code:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i /var/www/html/slowwmo-images/sjw.png -i rtsp://media.vezer.uk:4444/nimble/audio -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -video_track_timescale 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 -vf fps=25 -acodec aac -af aresample=44100 -f flv /var/www/html/slowwmo-live/live.ts
```

Why does `/usr/bin/ffprobe /var/www/html/slowwmo-live/live.ts` show 1k tbn when I need it to be 25?

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-video_track_timescale` is specific to the MOV muxer which handles generation of `.mov` and `.mp4` files and a few other variants.

`-f flv` forces the creation of the Adobe Flash Video container, typically used for `rtmp` streaming. It has a fixed timescale of 1000. Its extension is `.flv`

P.S. `.ts` indicates a MPEG-TS file, which is altogether another format and has a fixed timescale of 90000.

Comment: Thanks for all this clarification. It's made other problems clearer to me. I'll have to find another route other than concat (the reason I needed tbn to be 25)